# css jquery ui slider customize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, slider

i am looking at firebug but i can only see two elements

how can i turn this

[image]

into, for example this?

[image]

Do i have to manually add a class or something?

this is how i init

```
.slider({
                    value : $(this).attr('data-value'),
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100,
                    step: 5,
                    disabled: true,
                    slide: function( event, ui ) {  }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#slider-range-min").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: $(this).data('value'),
    min: 1,
    max: 700,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        ....
    }
});​
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#rangemin

Comment: thanks! with this and .ui-slider-range-min{background:black} i achieved it, maybe you want to edit and add the clasname ;)

Comment: i just wanted to show how it could done. customization is up to you :)